# When can I apply for an ETA for Sri Lanka?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, visas-on-arrival, sri-lanka, e-visas

My parents want to go to Sri Lanka in late September. According to them you need to apply for an ETA beforehand, so they've asked me to walk them through the process. However, during the application, I couldn't continue when I've tried to input their date of arrival and got an error message:

> Arrival date should be within 90 days

The [official site](http://www.eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/center.jsp?locale=en_US) doesn't show that information anywhere, at least neither in the English nor in the German version. Does that mean that my parents can apply for their ETA only in late June or later and we can simply postpone the application till then?

Comment: " Since you need to apply for an ETA beforehand" This is **wrong**, you can also get it on Arrival if entering by air

Comment: @Crazydre just repeating their statement, or rather the traveling organization ones.

Comment: Travel agencies often don't know what they're talking about. See my update. I guarantee you they can get it on arrival. All of that said, you can also apply online once it's less than 90 days left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it says that arrival should be within 90 days, then yes, that means all you have to do is wait until it's 90 days left, and apply then.

That said, the statement that:

> ...you need to apply for an ETA beforehand

is **wrong** if entering by air. At Colombo Airport, you can file the application and get the ETA before clearing Immigration, although it costs USD 40 instead of 35.

This is confirmed by the database used by airlines, [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=de&DE=lk&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Passengers traveling as tourists must obtain
>      an ETA on arrival, **or** before arrival at www.eta.gov.lk